# Why doesn't the C++ default destructor destroy my objects?

Tags: c++, default, destructor

The C++ specification says the default destructor deletes all non-static members. Nevertheless, I can't manage to achieve that.

I have this:

```
class N {
public:
    ~N() {
        std::cout << "Destroying object of type N";
    }
};

class M {
public:
    M() {
        n = new N;
    }
//  ~M() { //this should happen by default
//      delete n;
//  }
private:
    N* n;
};
```

Then this should print the given message, but it doesn't:

```
M* m = new M();
delete m; //this should invoke the default destructor
```

Comment: This is why automatic storage is preferred over dynamic storage. Only use dynamic allocation when you must.

Comment: @GMan:  Agreed obviously, but Oszkar still needs to know how & why this works.

Comment: @John: And he knows, hence "this is why..."

Comment: I definitely agree that automatic storage (or resource manager objects, like tr1::shared_ptr) is the way to go, but I just don't see why this doesn't work according to specification.

Comment: `n` is a pointer. The pointer is destroyed by the default destructor. What it points *to* is not, that is your responsibility.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

What makes you think the object `n` points to should be deleted by default?  The default destructor destroys the pointer, not what it's pointing to.

Edit:  I'll see if I can make this a little more clear.

If you had a local pointer, and it went out of scope, would you expect the object it points to to be destroyed?

```
{
    Thing* t = new Thing;

    // do some stuff here

    // no "delete t;"
}
```

The `t` pointer is cleaned up, but the `Thing` it points to is not.  This is a leak.  Essentially the same thing is happening in your class.

Comment: @OP: Because it has no way of knowing that it's okay to do that. You could have a pointer to something that should not be destroyed (in fact, it'll be quite common for that to be the case).

Comment: also even if you add in the commented out bit you may need to flush the stream brefore you actually see output

Comment: @T.J. Crowder: but still: isn't destroying the object what the specification requires?

@jk: why whould I need to flush the stream?

Comment: @Oszkar: the specification only requires automatic objects to be destroyed... In this case, the pointer *is* destroyed as soon as it goes out of scope. But what if `some stuff` transmitted the pointer to another object/function that does not go out of scope ? Should the `Thing` still be destroyed ?

Comment: @Fred Larson et al: Or anyone else here, what do you mean that the pointer is destroyed? If you look at my example here http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f7401ad0bd90407e you see that a pointer to the same object that was destroyed can still reference objects, why is that? Shouldn't the Dummy ptr be pointing to nothing if it is destroyed?

Comment: @Parham: it means that the memory allocated for that pointer is released to be used for other things. It does not mean that it is set to null.

Comment: Thanks, @FredLarson. So would that mean that it is just by chance that you can use a pointer, since the memory has not been used for anything else yet?

Comment: @Parham: Correct. Using the pointer after it has been destroyed is undefined behavior. It might work fine, it might cause the immediate collapse of the universe, or anything in between.

Answer (score 16):

Imagine something like this:

```
class M {
public:
    M() { }
//  ~M() {        // If this happens by default
//      delete n; // then this will delete an arbitrary pointer!
//  }
private:
    N* n;
};
```

You're on your own with pointers in C++.  No one will automatically delete them for you.

The default destructor will indeed destroy all member objects.  But the member object in this case is a pointer itself, not the thing it points to.  This might have confused you.

However, if instead of a simple built-in pointer, you will use a [smart pointer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/106508/what-is-a-smart-pointer-and-when-should-i-use-one), the destruction of such a "pointer" (which is actually a class) might trigger the destruction of the object pointed to.

Comment: Which is why smart pointers exist, so that there will be automatic destruction.

Comment: "The default destructor will indeed destroy all member objects. But the member object in this case is a pointer itself, not the thing it points to. This might have confused you." -> Indeed. That clarifies it. Thanks! :)

Comment: @Oszkar: I think you can un-accept an answer and then accept another. It seems that this one is more appropriate !

Comment: @RaphaelSP: I got several appropriate (and very nice!) answers, and decided to mark the first one, because it was hard to decide.

Answer (score 9):

The default destructor is destroying the pointer.  If you want to delete the `N` with `M`'s default destructor, use a smart pointer.  Change `N * n;` to `auto_ptr<N> n;` and `n` will be destroyed.

Edit:  As pointed out in comments, `auto_ptr<>` is not the best smart pointer for all uses, but it looks like what's called for here.  It specifically represents ownership:  the N in an M is there for the duration of the M and no longer.  Copying or assigning an `auto_ptr<>` represents a change in ownership, which is usually not what you want.  If you wanted to pass a pointer from M, you should pass a `N *` gotten from `n.get()`.

A more general solution would be `boost::shared_ptr<>`, which will be in the C++0x standard.  That can be used pretty much wherever a raw pointer would be used.  It's not the most efficient construct, and has problems with circular references, but it's generally a safe construct.

Another edit:  To answer the question in another comment, the standard behavior of the default destructor is to destroy all data members and base classes.  However, deleting a raw pointer simply removes the pointer, not what it points to.  After all, the implementation can't know if that's the only pointer, or the important one, or anything like that.  The idea behind smart pointers is that deleting a smart pointer will at least lead to the deletion of what it points to, which is usually the desired behavior.

Comment: You should really make sure you understand what is going on before using auto_ptr. Its copying and assignment semantics may not be what you would expect.

Comment: @David: I do understand that my example is not a wise design solution. I'm just trying to figure out the standard behaviour of default destructors. I would use tr1::shared_ptr (it's already included in gcc) or just store the object by value.

Sorry for not being specific enough with this question.

Comment: @Oszkar:  Yes, and the standard behavior is to delete the elements and base classes.  I'm sorry I didn't make that clearer.  I'll edit again.

Answer (score 6):

Is there any reason why you use a pointer when the pointed-to object seems to belong the contained object? Just store the object by value:

```
class M
{
    N n;

public:

    M() : n()
    {
    }
};
```

Comment: Of course that's the way to go. I'm just testing the behaviour of the default destructor. And it appears to me that it doesn't behave right.

EDIT: after reading all the answers, it does :)

Answer (score 4):

It is incorrect to say that the destructor *deletes* members. It invokes the destructor of each member (and base class), which for built-in types (like pointers) means doing nothing.

Matching **new**s with **delete**s is your responsibility (either manually, or with the help of smart pointers).

Answer (score 3):

Your argument might seem sound but that's not how things work for pointers.

`n` is actually being destructed but, what this means is that the `N*` destructor is being called which, it does NOT destruct whatever object `n` is pointing to. Think of the `N*`'s destructor as if it were an `int`'s destructor. It deletes its value, the same happens for a pointer, it deletes the address it is pointing to, but it doesn't need to delete whatever object is located at the address you just deleted.

Comment: Yeah, that answers it. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I think you may be confused about levels of indirection here. When an instance is destroyed, each data member does indeed get destroyed along with it. In your case, when an `M` is destroyed and `M::~M()` is called, its variable `n` really is destroyed. The problem is that `n` is a `N *`, so while the pointer is destroyed, the thing it points to is not.

`delete` does not work like this. Consider your simple statement:

```
delete n;
```

The above statement destroys the thing that `n` points to, which is an object of type `N`. It does not destroy `n` itself, which is an `N *` pointer.

There is a very good reason that `M::~M()` does not automatically call `delete n;` which is this: the `N` object referred to might be shared between several `M` objects, and if one `M` were destroyed, the rest would lose the `N` they were pointing at, leaving horrible dangling pointers everywhere. C++ does not attempt to interpret what you *meant* to do with your pointers, it just does what you *told* it to do.

In short, `M` really is destroying all of its members when it is destroyed, it's just that this destruction doesn't do what you think it should do. If you want a pointer type which takes ownership of an object and destroys it when the pointer is destroyed, look at `std::auto_ptr`.

Answer (score 2):

The default destructor looks like this:

```
~M()
{
}
```

The default destructor does not insert code to do anything with pointed-to things.  What if you had *n* pointing to a stack variable?  Automatically inserting a *delete n* would crash.

The default destructor calls the destructor on each member of the class (*member.~T()*).  For a pointer, that's a no-op (does nothing), just like myint.~int() does nothing, but for member classes with defined destructors, the destructor is called.

Here's another example:

```
struct MyClass {
public:
    MyClass() { .. } // doesn't matter what this does

    int x;
    int* p;
    std::string s;
    std::vector<int> v;
};
```

The default destructor in reality is doing this:

```
MyClass::~MyClass()
{
    // Call destructor on member variables in reverse order
    v.~std::vector<int>(); // frees memory
    s.~std::string();      // frees memory
    p.~int*();             // does nothing, no custom destructor
    x.~int();              // does nothing, no custom destructor
}
```

Of course, if you define a destructor, the code in your destructor runs *before* the member variables are destroyed (obviously, otherwise they would not be valid!).

Answer (score 1):

Try avoiding using pointers. They are last resort elements.

```
class N {
public:
    ~N() {
        std::cout << "Destroying object of type N";
    }
};

class M {
public:
    M() {
       // n = new N; no need, default constructor by default
    }
//  ~M() { //this should happen by default
//      delete n;
//  }
private:
    N n; // No pointer here
};
```

Then use it this way

```
main(int, char**)
{
    M m;
}
```

This will display Destroying object of type N

Comment: Pointers are vital in C++ for many purposes.  Know how to use them well.

Answer (score 1):

I think you could benefit from a very simple example:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  N* n = new N();
} // n is destructed here
```

This will not print anything either.

Why ? Because the `pointer` (`n`) is destructed, not the object pointed to `*n`.

Of course, you would not want it to destroy the object pointed to:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  N myObject;
  {
    N* n = &myObject;
  } // n is destructed here, myObject is not

  myObject.foo();
} // myObject is destructed here
```

You should remember that unlike languages like `C#` or `Java`, there are 2 ways to create objects in C++: directly `N myObject` (on the stack) or via `new` like in `new N()` in which case the object is placed on the heap and YOU are reponsible for releasing it at a later time.

So your destructor destroys the pointer, but not the object pointed to. Allocate the object without new (and without using a pointer) or use a `Smart Pointer` if you want it to be automatic.

Comment: The first example does point out very clearly how the destructor works. Thanks.

Comment: The second example still has memory leak and the first one too.

Comment: @krish_oza: The first one indeed has a memory leak (by design, since it actually show-cases the lack of execution of the destructor); however the second does not (it does not allocate memory).

Answer (score 1):

M destructor should have 'delete n'.

Comment: This should be posted as comment not answer.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using `new` to create instance, it won't delete by default.

Answer (score 0):

```
class N {
public:
    ~N() {
        std::cout << "Destroying object of type N";
    }
};

class M {
public:
    M() {
        n = new N;
    }
//  ~M() { //this should happen by default
//      delete n;
//  }
private:
    N* n;
};
```

and now the expectation is :

```
M* m = new M();
delete m; //this should invoke the default destructor
```

It will only happen, if the class M is derived from N:

```
class M: Class N {
...
```

Only in this situation,

```
M* m = new M()
```

will call constructor of N and then constructor of M, where as

```
delete m;
```

will automatically call destructor of M first and then N