# How to correctly delete a linked list?

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, linked-list, singly-linked-list

I tried to implement a singly linked list for my homework. Everything seemed to work perfectly until I tried it with linked list of linked lists, it failed to free the linked list inside and left some leaks. What I've done wrong? Some say I just ignore it the OS will clean up for me, but I really don't want to leave leaks.
Everything else seems ok, so I only post the destructor part.

```
template<typename T>
class linkedList
{
protected:
    node<T>* pHead;
    node<T>* pTail;
    int size;
public:
    linkedList() : pHead(nullptr), size(0), pTail(NULL) {};

    ~linkedList() { this->cleanup(); };

    void cleanup()
    {
        while (pHead) {
            node<T>* p = pHead;
            pHead = pHead->pNext;
            delete p;
        }
    };
```

I have tried it with different data types, and it works ok, but when I tried

```
auto l = new linkedList<linkedList<int>*>;
```

it failed to free the linked lists inside. What is wrong with this?
I need to use pointer because sometimes I need to know if it is NULL or not.

Comment: You delete the nodes, but you probably don't delete the data wrapped by the nodes (which you shouldn't!) You need to do that manually outside the list class.

Comment: Might be related to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/2403020/10077

Comment: `auto l = new linkedList<linkedList<int>*>;` -- So you want `linkedList` to somehow figure out that the `linkedList<int>*` data needs to have `delete` called on it?  And how is it going to know that those pointers came from a call to `new`?  Also, why are you using `new` to create the linked list?  Why not: `linkedList<linkedList<int>*>  l;`?;

Comment: If you need to tell the difference between an empty list and no list, use `std::optional<linkedList<int>>` and the problem will solve itself.

Comment: I think I get it, thank you guys.

Comment: The line `delete p;` will call the node's destructor, so your implementation of `node<T>` is relevant. Would you add that definition to your question?